# Laravel vue js Opening video in modal onClick not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So what i'm trying to do is pretty simple but for some reason is not working please let me show you.
This is my navigation bar written in vue js and here i'm holding almost all my vue components.

Navigation.vue

```
<template>
        <single-video :user_id="user_id" :video="this.video" :videoUser="this.videoUser" 
          :videoOptions="videoOptions"></single-video>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Navigation",
        data: function () {
            return {
                user_id: user_id,
                // isLogin: isLogin,
                video: {},
                videoUser: {},
                videoOptions: {
                    autoplay: true,
                    controls: true,
                    sources: [
                        {
                            src: "",
                            type: "application/x-mpegURL"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            openVideoModal(video){
                this.videoOptions.sources[0].src = 'storage/videos/' + video.id + '/' + video.id + '.m3u8';
                axios.get('video/' + video.channel_id).then(response => {
                    this.videoUser = response.data;
                }).catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status == 422) {
                        this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                    }
                    console.log('Error');
                });
                this.video = video;
                $('#singleVideo').modal('show');

            },
        },
    }

</script>
```

In one of my child component i have this method which calling openVideoModal() function in navigation. With the video id. So far it's working.

<a @click="$parent.openVideoModal(video)">

This one is my single video component which display the video itself.And is in modal ("singleVideo" modal)

single-video.vue

```
<video v-if="this.video"
                                ref="videoPlayer"
                                   id="my-video"
                                   class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
                                   controls
                                   preload="auto"
                                   width="749"
                                   height="421"
                                   :poster="this.video.thumbnail"
                                   data-setup="{}">
                            </video>
<script>

    import videojs from 'video.js';

    export default {
        props: ['user_id', 'video', 'videoUser', 'videoOptions'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                errors: {},
                singleVideo: {},
                player: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            if(this.videoOptions.sources[0].src) {
                this.player = videojs(this.$refs.videoPlayer, this.videoOptions, function onPlayerReady() {
              
                })
            }
        },
        methods: { 
        beforeDestroy() {
            if (this.player) {
                this.player.dispose()
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Please don't delete my question it is very important to me to solve this. I'm going nuts over it. :(

Comment: Hi, it is not working because you are missing vue component communication, both component do not communicate with each other, please go through this "https://medium.com/js-dojo/component-communication-in-vue-js-ca8b591d7efa" and make the parent component to communicate with the child. thanks

Comment: But i succeeded to pass the variable to the other component